# having trouble creating an outlet in a xib file

Tags: textview, xib, nib

I am working on a big project in swift 3 Xcode 8 I have created nib files that are being used in a pageviewcontroller. I created the nib with a coco file, i have a textview in the nib and when  connect the textview to the swift file it connects but when I run the program and get to the page with the text view the program crashes with error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException',
>   reason: '[
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key textFieldBox.

I'm trying to get to the point where the user writes in the text view box and it saves what they type.

[image: Screen shot of outlet connection]